# Function of X independent of X

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, independence

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables X~ Gamma(1,b) and 
Y~Gamma(n-1, b)  . Hence, $X$ and $Y$ are positive. Then ${\frac{X}{X+Y}}$ ~ Beta ( 1 , n-1)

$g(X+Y)=E\left[1_{X >1} \mid X+Y\right]$
and c is a value X+Y =c

$g(c)=
 $$E\left[1_{X >1} \mid X+Y=c\right]$ 
 =$E\left[1_{\frac{X}{X+Y}>\frac{1}{c}} \mid X+Y=c\right]=E\left[ 1_{\frac{X}{X+Y}>\frac{1}{c}}\right]$

Why is there independence? Is there a general rule?

Comment: Where is this identity coming from?

Comment: I rewrote it .,

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit: adapted after the rewriting of the question introducing the Gamma distributions.*

**There is no general rule.** In your setting, the identity crucially relies on the properties of the Gamma distribution. Specifically, the following, [quoting Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Related_distributions_and_properties):

> If $X \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha, \theta)$ and $Y \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(\beta, \theta)$  are independently distributed, then $X/(X + Y)$ has a Beta distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and $X/(X + Y)$ is independent of $X + Y$, which is $\operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha+\beta, \theta)$-distributed.

---

The identity however is **false** in general, and really relies on the particular Gamma distribution. For a very siimple counterexample, consider $X$ uniform on $\{\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}\}$, $Y$ uniform on $\{\frac{1}{10},\frac{7}{4}\}$ and independent of $X$, for instance, and $C=2$.

We first have, since $X<1$ a.s.,
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\frac{X}{X+Y} > \frac{1}{C}} \mid X+Y=C] = 
\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{X>1} \mid X+Y=C] =0\,.
$$
(Note that $X+Y=2$ has non-zero probability: namely, probability $1/4$).

However, without the conditioning,
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\frac{X}{X+Y} > \frac{1}{C}}]
= \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{X>Y}] = \frac{1}{2}\,,
$$
since $X>Y$ whenever $Y=1/10$.

Comment: I rewrote the question. thank you

Comment: That's an entirely different question now... you went from "arbitrary $X,Y$ to "something really relying on the particular distributions of $X,Y$."

Comment: @Pedros See  my edit.